# iPhone - Core Data Model Design Question

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm auditing the iTunesU iPhone development course by Stanford, and am trying to wrap my head around using Core Data.

Essentially, the application has two tabs that utilize Core Data:
1) Favorite Photos - This is a list of Locations (from Flickr) that the user has selected to "favorite" a photo for. (If there are no photos "favorited" in a given location it is removed from this list).
2) Recent Photos - This is a list of photos most recently viewed by the user.

My initial thought was to use two entities: Photo and Location, where Photo would have the a relationship "whereTaken" that would be a Location, and Location would have the inverse relationship "photos" to contain all Photo objects from that Location.

However, with this model, I get a little confused on how to keep track of whether or not a given Location has any "favorited" photos left.  The assignment suggested to keep an attribute in the Location entity to specify whether or not there are any "favorited" photos in that location.

So -- here are my questions:

1. Would it be better to create
   separate entities for
   "FavoritePhoto" and "RecentPhoto"
   rather than just "Photo"?
2. If not, is it suggested (or possible) to
   keep a subset of photos (only the
   "favorited" ones in the inverse
   relationship) in Location?
3. Or, do I need to iterate on the NSSet of
   Photo objects every time I remove a
   "favorited" photo to see if there
   are any other "favorited" photos
   left?  Or, perhaps keep a count of
   favorited photos as an attribute in
   Location?

Maybe, I'm going about this completely wrong -- either way, I'd appreciate any kind of advice, general or specific, regarding designing a Core Data model in this case.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Can a Location logically exist if it has no photos associated with it or should it just not show up in a particular UI element? Are only favorite Photos related to a Location or are there both favorite and non-favorite related photos?

Comment: Hi -- I think logically, a Location could exist if it has no photos associated with it, but really, if there are no favorite Photos associated with it, then it doesn't show up in the "Favorites" table view.  In regards to the relationship, I think photos could be related to a location even if they're not favorites because of the "Recent Photos" tab.  It would need the ability to re-open the recent photo and have an opportunity to mark it (and its location) as a favorite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up a bit on NSPredicate.  You can attach this to a fetch request to filter the photos you wish to retrieve.  Creating two different Photo entities is most likely a mistake.  You might want to add a BOOL attribute "isFavorite" to the Photo entity.  Then, when fetching the photos, you would use something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFavorite == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

You can also make slightly more complex predicates to filter for both favorite status and location.

[NSPredicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

Comment: Also, the relationship to the Location would more commonly just be called "location", and not something like "whereTaken"

Comment: Hi Mark -- thanks for the help.  So, in this case then, I would just need to use a more complex predicate to pull the favorites for a given location and if the result is empty, then I know the Location is not a favorite anymore, correct?  I think that makes sense.  I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fetched Property in the Location entity and have it only fetch the 'favorited' photos with the appropriate predicate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Carlos.  I don't think the prof even mentioned fetched properties in the class, so I didn't even know what they were.  In a quick glance at the documentation, that seems like it may be a viable option.  I'll see what I can do.  Thanks!